# How to turn on assert statements in junit4 runned with sbt?

Tags: java, junit, sbt, assert

I use sbt for development routines in my java project and  [junit-interface](https://github.com/sbt/junit-interface) for running tests.
But by default it ignores assert statements(assert for checking some invariant in underlying code). For example this test passes:

```
@Test
public void test() {
  // this is example; In reality assertion somewhere in code under test
  assert false; // not assertTrue(or whatever) from junit
}
```

My build.sbt file is fairly simple:

```
organization := "Kharandziuk"

name := "Some alg project"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "junit" % "junit" % "4.8.1" % "test",
    "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.10" % "test"
)

autoScalaLibrary := false

testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-a", "-q", "-v")

fork in run := true

javaOptions in run += "-ea"
```

How I can enable assert statements in tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it for separate tasks, eg. `test`s:

```
javaOptions in test += "-ea"
```

or simply set it everywhere:

```
javaOptions += "-ea"
```

Regardless, @MPirious is right in that you typically don't want to cause assertion failures through unit testing. A unit test is supposed to *sandbox* your code's logic

Comment: I try to add those option but nothing changed

Comment: @kharandziuk Are you running the test forked? (`fork in test := true` or `fork := true` for all)

Comment: I tried to set `fork := true` and now everything works. But when I change `fork in test := true` nothing happens.

Comment: You may also need `javaOptions in ThisBuild += "-ea"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of "assert" is a keyword in java. They need to be enabled by  by supplying JVM option "-ea".

I think, you want to use the static methods of org.junit.Assert.

```
@Test
public void test() {
  org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(SOME CONDITION);
}
```

Comment: No, I just want to enable invariant checks in code under test.