# How to make Java asserts work in sbt project?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, assert

I have an SBT project with some Scala and Java code. `assert`s don't work for me when placed in the java code.

The project structure looks like

```
src/
    main/
        java/
        scala/
```

I've tried to add

```
fork := true
javaOptions += "-ea"
```

but it doesn't help.

Example of Java code

```
public class Assertions {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("before");
        assert true;
        assert false;
        System.out.println("after");
    }
}
```

P.S. I've tried to search and there are a few similar questions already like [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637692/how-to-turn-on-assert-statements-in-junit4-runned-with-sbt) but the proposed solutions don't work for me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try `javaOptions in ThisBuild += "-ea"`.